# Is this a true statement about open sets in a topological space?

Tags: general-topology

Is the below statement about open sets a true one?  I'm pretty sure it is but it's been about a decade since I first learned topology and I'm having trouble finding this in a reliable (or any) source.  I'm not asking or looking for a proof, I just need to verify if this is true.

> A subset $S$ of a topological space $(X, \tau)$ is open if for every $x \in S$, there exists an open set $U \subseteq S$ such that $x \in U$.

Thanks.

Comment: If you take the union of these open sets then it is equal to $S$ and it is open. Hence $S$ is open.

Comment: Yes. And replace the "if" with "iff".

Comment: Not sure why this question deserved a downvote - this is a useful equivalence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's true.  This is equivalent to saying that $S$ is the union of a collection of open sets; such a thing is open.

Comment: Thanks..  Makes perfect sense now.  Bit rusty on my topology here.